# Can the sidebar in OPERA and other browsers be removed automatically using javascript or CSS?

Tags: browsers

In Opera there is a sidebar which wrecks the desktop layout of our website. Is there a piece of code which can be placed on our website to automatically remove all sidebars in all browsers?

Comment: "to automatically remove all sidebars in all browsers?" You don't feel that you should let users decide for themselves how they want to see your website? Shouldn't you invest instead time into making sure that no single sidebar or anything else "wrecks the desktop layout", because anyway you can  never control how people will see your content. I am sure your users will thank you for that.

Comment: How does a sidebar wreck the desktop layout of your website anyway? It can't be just because the screen is a bit narrower, otherwise how would your website work with a variety of desktop screen sizes?

Comment: The CSS media query seems to be on the cusp and the little sidebar causes the layout to break - It would be easier if I had code to just remove sidebars but maybe this doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't believe there is a piece of code like that. But please realize that if the layout breaks on your screen with the sidebar open, it likely breaks for someone else who has a slightly smaller screen, even without any sidebars.